# Is there a way to launch specific test case from testSuite(made with soapUI) trough jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin, soapui, jenkins-plugins

as you could see in the title i have a question ! I am looking for a way to launch a specific testCase in a testSuite. The testSuite was made by the soft SoapUi. One testSuite is one xml file which contains multiple test Cases. Through the Jenkins soft i want to execute a job to try my xml script. For that i use a maven-plugin but my problem is that i don't know how to specify to execute one test Case or two and not all each time. For example if i execute my script once and all testCase succeed except 2 which failed, how can i execute with the same script the only two test Cases which failed.

cordially

Comment: Your question, together with the below comment, sounds like you are not sure what you are trying to accomplish. In any case, this is more of a discussion, which SO does not really support. See [Ask].

Answer (score 3):

Bit late to the party on this one, but you can do this in the following way - Within the Pom.xml add the following entries:

```
                <configuration>
                  <reportName>SoapUI report</reportName>
                  <projectFile>name-of-project-file</projectFile>
                  <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/reports/</outputFolder>
                  <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                  <exportAll>false</exportAll>
                  <printReport>true</printReport>
                  <testSuite>${testSuite}</testSuite>
                  <testCase>${testCase}</testCase>
                  <projectProperties>
                    <projectProperty>Environment=${Environment} /projectProperty>
                  </projectProperties>
                </configuration>
```

TestSuite can then be referenced in the command line using

```
mvn test -DtestSuite="name of your test suite"
```

Or if you want to specify the name of your test case:

```
mvn test -DtestCase="name of your test case"
```

Or if you want to specify both:

```
mvn test -DtestCase="names of your test case" -DtestSuite="name of your test suite"
```

**Update**

I've found that you will need to specify -DtestSuite if you want to run a specific test case

Answer (score 2):

So to deal with your scenario, you can implement something typically called 'tagging' in SOAP UI test cases.

Lets discuss some example like,

#### Scenario 1 :

- You can add testCase property 'Runmode' whose value could be like 'Y' or 'N'.
- Similarly there would be one Project Property 'testExecution' which would contain tescases to be executed.
- Now while running the Jenkins job you can pass the list of test cases as parameter to maven SOAP UI project like -DtestExecution="testcase1,testcase4".
- Primarily, in  SetUp script of project, parse these test cases from testExecution property and assign RunMode for the testcases. Also handle the cases if user doesn't mention any testcase, in that case every test case must run.

#### Scenario 2 :

- You can specify some tags like 'SmokeTests', 'Regression', 'Integration Tests'.
- And add Project Property like 'TestExecution'.
- Again, you can pass its value from maven parameter like -DTestExecution = 'SmokeTest'
- Primarily, you would be defining property say 'TAG' to every test case whose value could be 'Smoke Test', Integration Test and so on.
- So based on value of TestExecution, you can control the execution of test cases.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thx you for you answer :) but actually it's to much complicate to apply this solution to my situation because there is more than 1000 testCase and over than 500 testSuite :/ i look forward about a solution on maven plugin side or an other plugin if there is one !

Comment: @nayan, how you set TestExecution in maven.pom xml? I have add tags in the test cases level e.g Regression, when running maven with -DTestExecution still run all test cases?

Answer (score 1):

So in that case, there are some parameter you can use with the maven plugin for controlling functional tests.

### Plugin Settings

#### test settings

projectFile : Specified the name of the SoapUI project file to use, default value is
${pom.artifactId}-soapui-project.xml

#### testSuite### : Specifies the name of the TestSuite to run

#### testCase### : Specifies the name of the TestCase to run

endpoint : Overrides the service endpoint to be invoked by any TestRequests

host : Overrides the target host:port to be invoked by any TestRequests

username : Overrides the username used by any TestRequests run

password : Overrides the password used by any TestRequests run
domain : Overrides the domain used by any TestRequests run

printReport : Controls if a small test report should be printed to the console (true/false)

outputFolder : Set which folder results/reports are saved to

junitReport : Turns on creation of JUnit-reports, (true/false)

exportAll : Controls if all test requests should be exported (default only exports errors),
(true/false)
settingsFile : Specifies SoapUI settings file to use

wssPasswordType : Specifies WSS password type

project.password : Specifies password for encrypted project

settingsFile.password : Specifies password for encrypted settings file

globalProperties : Sets global properties

projectProperties : Sets project properties

saveAfterRun : Saves project file after run

testFailIgnore : Ignore failed tests.

reportFormat : Sets formats for created report. Pro only.

reportName : Sets which report to create. Pro only.

coverage : Sets the output to include Coverage HTML reports. Pro only.

environment : Sets the active environment. Pro only.